# Can we pass list in silverlight navigation?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, navigation, query-string

I am developing silverlight application for sharepoint 2010. I want to pass list from one page to another. I am using silverlight navigation. I know how to pass values between pages.

```
myFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/foo.xaml?customerId=1234", UriKind.Relative));

string customerId = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["customerid"];
```

But what if I want to pass `List<string> customers` in querystring. Can I pass it ? If yes then can you please tell me how to do that ? If there is any other better way to pass list between pages then please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot pass any type of object along with the call to Navigate.
In your case, serializing your list (eg to xml) might be viable. You could then include the serialized version in the query string.

Depending on your situation, you might also consider adopting one of the other navigation frameworks.

[Jounce](http://jounce.codeplex.com/) is a full blown MVVM framework, but that doesnt mean you cant just use it for navigation.